# How to disable auto leveling of sound

Tags: windows-7

How is it possible to disable auto leveling when playing music?

If I got a track with a break or quiet part and the sound level rise after the break somehow windows normalizes the sound and turns down the volume!

Comment: What audio driver software is installed? Some voice communication software may also turn down the volume automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any third party software that has this feature, you'll have to remove that. If there is no 3rd party software, you can try disabling Loudness Equalization:

1. Right click the sound icon in the system tray then click Playback Devices.
2. Select your output device (usually Speakers) then click Properties.
3. Click the Enhancements tab and deactivate Loudness Equalization.

   [image]

Not all audio devices support this feature, or some may call it by another name.

Comment: Applicable for all modern Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for auto leveling of all sounds playing on Windows.
I used a third-party system-wide equalizer (Equalizer APO),
then reduced the preamp to -16~-20 and increasing the low db channels, here is my config.txt:

```
Preamp: -16 dB
Include: example.txt
GraphicEQ: 25 -5; 40 -5; 63 15; 100 15; 160 14; 250 9; 400 -12; 630 -12; 1000 -12; 1600 -12; 2500 -12; 4000 -3; 6300 0; 10000 10; 16000 11
```

It worked! You can edit any of the above channels to your choice and save the file. See Equalizer APO tutorial.